# JasperReports PDF Cyrillic font overlap

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

My PDF report not being filled well, cyrillic letters do overlapp each other. please take a look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkhIA.jpg)

When I use another encoding - I cant see charactes (Only question marks), but it does not stack.

I added FontExtension library using JasperReports and I am using Times New Roman and CP1251 encoding   [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbnNl.png). Jasper doesnt print any symbols except numbers without FontExtension.

here is simple code:

```
case (Reporter.PDF): {

                Logging.info("pdf");
                exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

                response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="
                        + reportName + ".pdf");
                exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));
                exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint)); 
                exporter.exportReport();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
```

***DOC and xlsx works fine.***

thank you.

Comment: `I added FontExtension library` - What is it?

Comment: Did you try utf-8?

Comment: Try leaving PDF Font Name empty for the font extension, and using Identity-H as PDF Encoding.

Comment: @AlexK it is jar file, which contains ttf files and xml bindings. it helps JasperReports with using cyrillic and other charsets in pdf report. Pdf uses Itext and somehow needs thia extension, I'm not sure.

Comment: @dada67 I'll try a bit later, thanks!

Comment: @AlexK there is no utf8 in encoding list

Comment: @dada67
dude, I have no idea how, but you saved me! thanks a lot!